# how to setup or what to setup on urban airship and on itunes for inapp purchase?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am new to urban airship's inapp purchase. I am familiar with itunes's inapp purchase. But i have no idea about urban airship's inapp purchase.

I have made app(production) on urban airship and I have implemented code for inapp purchase with development/production keys. But i don't have idea how to setup or manage the inapp purchase on urban airship.

I have searched a lot for tutorial and documents to setup inapp on urban airship, but could not  get anything..

Please can someone provide the link for tutorial or document to setup inapp on urban airship.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Complete set of tutorials, which will explain you step by step procedure is given in the site of urbanairship itself.
Here is the link to that https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Exporting+Your+Push+Notification+Key
https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+iOS%3A+Push#GettingStartediOSPush-3ObjCImplementation

Comment: thanks for reply. I have already completed these processes. But i want to know the steps for inapp purchase setup. Means , how to specify price and app for inapp ... ???